# Get router value from url in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app, and a component that is supposed to load a set of value of the url

```
        <PersistGate persistor={rootStore.persistor}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <ErrorBoundary>
                  <Preloader history={history} /> <== this need to read the url
                  <PasswordChecker></PasswordChecker>
                  <RouteDispatcher></RouteDispatcher> <== this contain the list of routes
                </ErrorBoundary>
            </Router>
        </PersistGate>
```

In my `RouteDispatcher` path I have setup the route like this :

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/ws/:ws/pj/:pj/ds/:ds" component={HomeDatastore} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/ws/:ws/pj/:pj" component={HomeProject} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/ws/:ws" component={HomeWorkspace} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

how would I get the value of `ws=:ws` `pj=:pj` etc...

I was thinking of doing it with a regex, but I wonder if there is a better way. Preloader is outside the routeDispatcher, so I don't seem to find a good  way to get the value.

Comment: using wihRouter HOC ,Something like this.props.match.params.ws?

Comment: I don't know how to use in a functional component.

Answer (score 2):

React router provides `params` into the component. Check `props.match.params`. I see that you have a custom component `PrivateRoute` so first check props in `PrivateRoute`.

Comment: privateRoute does get stuff in the props, but when I log my props in my functional component `Preloader` it's empty. I wonder if it is because Preloader is outside of 
<RouteDispatcher>

Comment: if you want to use route props ({match, params, location}) outside `<Route />` you should to use `withRouter` for React.Component or  `matchPath` with `useLocation` for React.FunctionComponent. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web

Answer (score 1):

May be try using **useParams()** hook. It gives you a way to access the URL params

Reference: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-router-hooks-will-make-your-component-cleaner/

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-useparams-hooks-q8g37

This might help you get started with it

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ComponentName() {
  let params = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
     {params.ws}
     {params.pj}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this looked nice, but it doesn't work outside of the <Switch> tag, and my component is outside of it

Comment: @Bobby May be try restructuring your router config :)

Comment: well, it s a component that should be always there not depending on the routes and rendered only once. I can't put it inside Switch, and add it to every component is not the best choice either. So I think the best is just have it outside and find a way for it to work.